# Display multiple Trending Topics at the same time

Tags: twitter

I want to display multiple Twitter trending topics at the same time. For example, I want to view Worldwide, Turkey and United States side by side in real time. Apparently, this is not possible on twitter.com. Is there a webapp to achieve that?

Comment: You might be able to use [TweetDeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com). They have a Chrome web app for in-browser use, and they also have an Adobe Air app that is for the desktop (available on Windows/Mac/Linux).

Comment: I've been using TweetDeck as well. It doesn't seem to be able to do that. My related question on Super User: [Display multiple Trending Topics at the same time in TweetDeck](http://superuser.com/q/341638/13567)

Comment: I built a mashup that shows Twitter trending topics for worldwide locations using their API, though not side by side & all at the same time. Check it out - http://applab.azurewebsites.net/trends.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The websites [What the Trend](http://whatthetrend.com/) & [TrendsMap](http://trendsmap.com/) track Twitter Trends. They don't exactly match your requirement but come close.

If you'd like to build something yourself, there are free API's from [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3awoeid) & [What the Trend](http://api.whatthetrend.com/)